# Combining column vectors and then merge it to data table of specific format

Tags: r, vector, merge, datatable

I want to create a data table in `R` that shows the final results in a nice format.
My final results are the following:

```
NENA.day <- c(42)
NENA.weeks <- c(38, 40, 41)
EQ.day <- c(20)
EQ.weeks <- c(17, 12, 12)
K.day <- c(10)
K.weeks <- c(12, 15, 14)
```

The data table should look like this:

[image]

How can I combine all vectors in that way, that I get the following table with the respective column and row names?
The data table in the picture is created in Excel, the result data table should be created in `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the vectors in a `list` and `split` it to group

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'NENA|EQ|K'))
out <- sapply(split(lst1, sub("\\..*", "", names(lst1))), unlist)
row.names(out) <- toupper(sub(".*\\.(.)\\D+(\\d*)", "\\1\\2", row.names(out)))
```

-output

```
out
#   EQ  K NENA
#D  20 10   42
#W1 17 12   38
#W2 12 15   40
#W3 12 14   41
```

As we have a lot of vector objects, an easier option to get them into a `list` would be with `mget` (returns a `named` `list`) after we get the object names as strings from `ls`.  Once, it is in a `list`, then we `split` the `list` to groups of nested list by removing the substring from the `names` i.e. removing the '.day', '.weeks', loop over the `list`. with `sapply` and `unlist` the nested `list` to create a singel `vector` for each of the 'EQ', 'K', 'NENA'.

---

Or another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
enframe(lst1) %>%
   unnest(c(value)) %>% 
   separate(name, into = c('name', 'dayweek'), sep="\\.") %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(name)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
   select(-rn) %>%
   mutate(dayweek = str_c(toupper(substr(dayweek, 1, 1)), 
                    rowid(dayweek), sep="+")) %>%
   column_to_rownames('dayweek')
```

-output

```
#    EQ  K NENA
#D+1 20 10   42
#W+1 17 12   38
#W+2 12 15   40
#W+3 12 14   41
```

Comment: Sorry, but this yields not what I expected

Comment: @Michi sorry, not clear.  It is showing the expected as your expected output except the `D+` or `W+`

Comment: @Michi Do you want a `kable` or `formattable` table?

Comment: If I use your code, this yields to an error message. Also, I can't see where you use in your code my result vectors (```EQ.day```, ```EQ.weeks``` and so on)?

Comment: @Michi It is in `lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'NENA|EQ|K'))`. Based on the code you have created those objects in the global env.  which I am getting the value in a list with `mget`

Comment: @Michi the mget does the same as `list(NENA.day = NENA.day, NENA.weeks = NENA.weeks, ...)`

Comment: The second version with ```tidyverse``` gives the expected output. Thank you! A ```data.frame``` is here created. Now, I am wondering whether there might be problems calling the this ```data.frame```when I want to output it in ```RShiny``` as an ```DT::renderDataTable({})```??

Comment: @Michi If it is created, then there shouldn't be any issue